# Does any one know how to make alternative to Google recently start page in java swing?

Tags: java, javascript, swing

Has anyone idea how to make recently Google Search page in java swing?
Please take a look at `http://www.google.com`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Nice effect :-)

If you wanted to do this in Swing, I would take the following approach:

- Render the original screen to an offscreen BufferedImage
- Render the new screen to an offcreen BufferedImage
- Do an animated transition between the two by drawing the new screen then painting over it with the correct portions of the old screen, twisted and rotated to the right location (you can use the Java2D AffineTransformation for the rotating/twisting)

The tricky bit will be getting the position to change over time in a way that looks visually appealing and doesn't cause any nasty visual artefacts. This will take some maths and quite a bit of trial and error!

Comment: Actually I think you'd want to render each of the components on the original (front) screen separately, since they move independently. They are then just rotated to match the orientation of where they meet the zip.